# How to store date_popup fileld in mysql

Tags: forms

For some reason I cannot save the value of my date_popup field (comment_date) to mysql database. 
I need to use default value from existing field (field_due_date6) and store the new value to this field.
So I do the following:

```
function custom_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['comment_date'] = array(
      '#date_format' => 'Y-m-d',
      '#date_year_range' => '0:+1',
      '#type' => 'date_popup',
      '#weight'=>1,
      '#datepicker_options' => array('minDate' => 0),
      '#default_value' => $form['#node']->field_due_date6['und'][0]['value']
    );
}
```

Then I'm trying to submit it to database:

```
function custom_support_comment_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $node = node_load($form_state['values']['nid']);
  $node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);

  if($form_state['values']['comment_date']) {
    $node_wrapper->field_due_date6->set($form_state['values']['comment_date']);
  }
  $node_wrapper->save();  
}
```

But when I click Submit button I got the error -

```
EntityMetadataWrapperException: Invalid data value given. Be sure it matches the required data type and format. в функции EntityMetadataWrapper->set() (строка 122 в файле Z:\home\dd1\www\sites\all\modules\entity\includes\entity.wrapper.inc).
```

Could you please specify what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Node Field must be expecting date field value in unixtimestamp format while the custom form will return the value in the format mention as '#date_format' => 'Y-m-d'. View of your form submit values will look like.

[image]

You should run the submit date value through [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to get the unxtimestamp value for it before assigning it to node field.

```
$node_wrapper->field_due_date6->set(strtotime($form_state['values']['comment_date']));
```